# How can I perform autoscaling in amazon ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I would like to know how can  I perform autoscaling in amazon ec2 instance. Do amazon support vertical autoscaling or not?

Is there any option of memory based or CPU based autoscaling?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `vertical autoscalin` ? please elaborate what are your requirement .

Comment: means memory based or CPU based autoscaling. I know that AWS supports autoscaling by distributing the load across multiple instances. I would lik eto know if it can increase the CPU or memory based on user defined threshhold on a single instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would lik eto know if it can increase the CPU or memory based on user defined threshhold on a single instance?

No, it does not. Not at-least at the time of writing this. They might add that feature in the offing.

In current situation, the only way to ad more CPU/MEM to an instance is to shut it down and then `change instance type`. This option is available in AWS Console and I am not sure of APIs.

While changing the instance type, you can choose a `bigger type of instance` which will eventually get you more CPU/MEM.

There is no way to add more CPU/MEM to a running instance at the moment. In fact, there is no way to add  CPU/MEM to a current instance without changing its instance type.

Autscaling does not do this either.

Comment: wouldn't the coward down voters have guts to comment why they are downvoting.

Comment: means i cant apply autoscale policy to my existing instance ? FYI i have not downvoted your answer :)

Comment: NO, not in a fashion that you want. I would suggest you to raise this query on AWS forum to see if AWS is considering this feature. They're very responsive to the customer needs.

Comment: if i have to attach this policy to an existing instance then what should i do ?re create the instance?

Comment: Autoscaling does not work with instances which were launched without autoscaling. Autoscaling will create its own instance. So, You cannot attach you autoscaling policy to your existing instances. So apparently, you have to recreate the instance via autoscaling policy.

Comment: i am so confused, @lloyd bank is saying it is possible and you are saying its not !! :( what to do now

Comment: Don't get confused. lloyd's answer is on a different track and it does not answer you issue. you want to do it on the existing instance. Please read lloyd answer carefully, he nowhere address how to do this on an existing instance. Also his response with respect to `If you want a bigger VPS box` is irrelevant because that is not what you want. You want to increase the CPU/MEM, not the disk space.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43307/discussion-between-user3086014-and-slayedbylucifer)

Comment: how can i launch an instance with autoscaling ? i cant find an option to do that.